# Lightswitch HTML Client (auto update a parameter based on another parameter)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

What im trying to achieve is this:

A user searches through a table using a parameter from a query created within lightswitch, for example **firstname**. on the second tab i want the parameter here (referencing another table) to replicate this in real time. So if a user types in 'Adam' on the 1st screen parameter, I want the 2nd screen parameter to also say 'Adam'

any tips on how I could do this using javascript? cheers

Comment: Can you not reuse the same parameter for both? place the parameter textbox before the tab control.

Comment: they are referencing 2 different tables, one being the main and the other a sub table of that, solved this issue why creating the table view through the main table